# What is the "akd" process, and do I need to allow it to connect to the internet?

Tags: macos, firewall

I use Little Snitch as a Mac OS firewall. Usually, it's fairly clear to me what needs to connect to the internet and what doesn't. However, I can't figure out what `akd` is or does, and why it needs to connect to `gsa.apple.com.akadns.net`:

[image]

Could anyone give me any insight on the implications of blocking it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't want iCloud so I permabanned this

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Little Snitch Research Assistant tells you what it is.

> akd is part of the AuthKit (authentication/authorisation) framework. Also used in the process of authenticating of iCloud and other accounts using Apple ID.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So my Google account for Mail would use this, then? I don't use iCloud.

Comment: @Will I could speculate so, but I'm not sure why it would try to connect to an Apple domain if you're not using an iCloud account. You could try denying all connections by akd and seeing if Mail still functions correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Googling for scraps of info, I can't find anything complete, but it appears to be the Auth Kit daemon. A daemon that handles authentication needs of the OS.

According to [Know your Mac OS X processes at Triviaware](http://triviaware.com/macprocess/id/16004) it's located at
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKit.framework/Versions/A/Support/akd`

Comments below imply that it is new to El Capitan & is used to authenticate the App Store. App Store login fails if you block it.

Comment: "App Store login fails if you block it."  - That is wrong in my experience.  As an experiment I blocked akd from connecting to gsa.apple.com & gsa.apple.com.akadns.net.  Later in the day a notice came of updates available.  Opened app store and updated Keynote, Pages, and Numbers app.  No issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this process comes from `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKit.framework/Versions/A/Support/akd`
which is the authenticator for the App Store, the only thing I can put to you is, are you using your GoogleMail as a Apple Store Account?

Bearing in mind you don't have to exclusively use an iCloud account to have a Store account.  You can use any e-mail address you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This A made no sense ... till I noticed it's in relation to a comment within it : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240108/what-is-the-akd-process-and-do-i-need-to-allow-it-to-connect-to-the-internet#comment295052_240148. Because the Q makes no reference to Google or email or gmail.