# "AKauthorization remote view" ? Did someone hack my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro

So my macbook air was making a lot of noise. I opened the activity monitor and saw "akd" and "AKauthorization remote view" consuming most of the CPU (50%)+. So I stopped it and completely erased my macbook thinking it got hacked. Does anyone know what "AKauthorization remote view"  is?

Comment: 'akd' is a known macOS process - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240108/what-is-the-akd-process-and-do-i-need-to-allow-it-to-connect-to-the-internet

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely you have been hacked. A process on your Mac is likely trying to verify your Apple ID with Apple's Sign On services.

- AK = AuthKit
- AS = Authentication Services

## Private AuthKitUI Framework

`AKAuthorization` appears to be part of Apple's private AuthKitUI framework. This framework is stored at `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKitUI.framework` on macOS.

The public [Authentication Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices) likely uses AuthKitUI to provide the user interface:

> Use the Authentication Services framework to improve the experience of users when they enter credentials to establish their identity.
>
> - Give users the ability to sign into your services with their Apple ID.
> - ...

It is likely **AKAuthorizationRemoteViewService** is a user interface element that shows content provided by a remote service.

See [jujigo
/
DragonBuild](https://github.com/jujigo/DragonBuild/blob/f290d83ca298123eba25c9e3479929ded2399233/sdks/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKitUI.framework/AuthKitUI.tbd) source that mentions this framework's contents.

Given AuthKit (AK) is a System Programming Interface (SPI) – and thus private to Apple's engineers – only Apple can authoritatively answer this question. You should provide [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback) about this behaviour.